# Obtener la longitud de la variable almacenada en tabla de la database con codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql

Resulta que en mi base de datos tengo una tabla que se llama *votaciones*, en la cual dentro de la columna  *opción* almaceno

a y b

Entonces quiero obtener la cantidad total de 'a' almacenados en la tabla como también la cantidad total de 'b' almacenado en la tabla.

**¿Cúal seria la forma correcta de hacerlo con CodeIgniter?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo con una clausula where en la consulta sql

Por ejemplo en tu modelo podrías hacer algo como:

```
function getOpciones($opcion){
  $this->db->select("opcion");
  $this->db->from("votaciones");
  $this->db->where("opcion",$opcion);

  if($query = $this->db->get()){
    return $query->num_rows();
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

Donde el parámetro opción seria "a" o "b" y obtendrías el numero de filas devueltas en la consulta.